# How do I close a question that has not received a suitable answer?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I have a couple of questions that I have asked previously but none of the answers given were the answers that I was looking for (so I have not marked any of them as the correct answer).

How do I close these questions so that I stop being prompted to mark and answer as correct and/or offer a bounty?

Comment: You do not have enough reputation to close questions. Furthermore, closing a question requires 5 people's approval who can close. This should probably be asked on meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Ideally the questions should stay until a suitable answer is supplied. Alternatively change them to CW questions.

Comment: What good would changing them to CW do? This makes it even less likely that they receive answers any time soon.

Comment: Simple to say, but many times there's just no answer coming...or there are "answers", but they're incorrect or misleading.

Answer (score 0):

The questions about Entity Framework you are referring to received high upvotes, which means they were of interest to the community.  Only a person with high rep can vote to delete them (I believe five votes from different users are required), and they are unlikely to do so, given the community interest.

[EF in real life, I want to believe (Does anyone have good pointers to non-trivial EF 1.0(3.5) or 4.0 examples?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028697/ef-in-real-life-i-want-to-believe-does-anyone-have-good-pointers-to-non-trivial)

[Entity Framework, WCF & updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803980/entity-framework-wcf-updates)